# jquery datatables table breaks when refreshing data

Tags: jquery, datatables

Refreshing data on the fly causes my table to completely break. Imagine stomping on an empty soda can. Then when the data repopulates it goes back to normal size. I am trying to see if anyone has had similar problems and if so what was your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table elements (td, th etc) need to have some fixed width/height/padding/margin settings in the CSS  assigned for it. Maybe you should first render your table without any data for testing purposes - empty table. Add min-width or padding or whatever to have the table render the way you want without any data. Once you can do that, then add the data and now if you refresh it, the table may not break any more.

Comment: Ok, I was thinking it was something along those lines, I recently inherated another developers work, so Im trying to sort through known issues to get things fixed, but I have yet to do anything with datatables so, kinda new to it in a manor of speaking, thanks